# It possible to change the style of scrollbar of select?

Tags: html, css

Hi i want to change the style of scrollbar inside of a select componente like this :

```
<select id="selectId" class="selectList`enter code here`"> 
<option>P1</option>
<option>P2</option>
<option>P3</option>
<option>....</option>
<option>PN</option>
</select>
```

I have this select with many items (something like 30/40 items) and i would like to change the css of the scrollbar that appear automatically (if the are many items)

I read that to apply the change to the scrollbar need to modify something like this :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

But the css changes doesn't apply to the scrollbar also if i try to pass in front the class or the id of the select
How can i apply the css to the scrollbar of a select ?

Comment: Check this out as well https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ , if doesn't work share the code over StackBlitz will have a look